# Is is possible to have the history metadata by row in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

Is it possible to have the history metadata of a row in databricks?
Something like:

```
SELECT column1, column2, VERSION_NUMBER, VERSION_TIMESTAMP 
FROM table
```

| col1 | col1 | VERSION_NUMBER | VERSION_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 0 | 2023-11-26 08:00:00 |
| First | row updated | 1 | 2023-11-27 08:00:00 |
| Second | row | 1 | 2023-11-27 08:00:00 |

Comment: Databricks has a [slowly changing dimension/CDC](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/cdc.html) type DLT that would likely suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the [Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) functionality on your Delta Lake table, but the detailed history will be available only from the point when it's enabled.  Also, it's not recommended to keep it for a long time because it will affect performance the recommended way of using it - read change feed as a stream, and append all changes into another table.